# how to use a subroutine if some module is already installed

Tags: perl

Imagine I am writing a Perl distribution and I don't like to force people to install some extra dependencies (let's say, the `JSON` package, just as an example).

Now I want to use the `JSON::true` subroutine **if available.**

If not, I will use some local fallback.

I end up writing something like this:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub _my_true_subroutine; 
INIT {
    eval {
        require JSON;

        if (my $t = JSON->can("true")) {
            no warnings q<redefine>;
            *_my_true_subroutine = $t;
        }
    };
}

sub _my_true_subroutine { -1 }

use feature qw<say>;

say "true is @{[ _my_true_subroutine ]}";
```

and it works fine, calling one code or another depending if `JSON` is installed or not.

However I am not 100% sure about this approach.

Any suggestions?

Is there any side effect that I may not be aware of?

I find this example from `Function-Fallback-CoreOrPP` that seems the same except it decides at runtime (the result of `eval {...}` can be cached in a constant) which implementation should be used. Is it safe to execute multiple times?

```
sub clone {
    my $data = shift;
    goto FALLBACK unless eval { require Data::Clone; 1 };
 
  STANDARD:
    return Data::Clone::clone($data);
 
  FALLBACK:
    require Clone::PP;
    return Clone::PP::clone($data);
}
```

Comment: I don't know if you're aware, but you're overriding the sub with the value of whether `JSON` has the `true` function or not, not the value of `true()`. Also, in the second example, it seems insane to me to continuously evaluate the check during runtime. I don't like the goto either, but I can remain indifferent there. This sort of stuff should be done in the compile phase (`BEGIN`) imho.

Comment: Indeed what I what is the value of JSON::true on this context, but in other cases I want a subroutine (like the support for base64 url enconded strings that is not present on older versions of Perl, etc). Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can do all that in the sub definition

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
    
sub tt { 
    my $ret;

    my $coderef = eval { 
        require JSON;
        JSON->can("true");  # probably needn't be in eval
    };  
    if ( $coderef ) {  
        say "\tYes got that installed and have the capability";
        $ret = $coderef->(@_);  # or: goto $coderef;
    }   
    else { 
        say "\tDefining our sub for the job";
        $ret = "Test truth for |@_|";
    };  

    return $ret;
}

say "Hi $$";

say tt( qw(well hello) );
```

The call to `->can` is under eval "*if you need to be extra paranoid*" per [UNIVERSAL](https://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL#$obj-%3Ecan(-METHOD-))

This way the `require` and the retrieval of the code reference runs every time the sub is called, so if there are *a lot* of calls that may need to be modified.  (Or if you don't like the aesthetic of it.)  On the other hand, this way we re-test for the capability when needed.

Also note that `can` won't know about a possible `AUTOLOAD` mechanism; see docs.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if `JSON` is installed, and if it is, all calls to `JSON->true` will work throughout your code no problem. If it isn't installed, you can completely override the `JSON->true` with your own sub. This way, you don't have to use an intermediary subroutine. Your code will work whether the module is installed or not using the original `JSON->true` call throughout.

In the below code, if `JSON` is installed, it'll do the right thing. If not, `JSON->true` will print `Y`. You can test this by changing the `require JSON;` line to something like `require JSONX;`.

The `eval` works by checking if it can successfully load `JSON`. If it can, the eval returns true (ie. `1`). If it can't, it returns `undef` and the `if not` condition succeeds, triggering the remapping of the `JSON->true` sub. Note too that there's no need to disable any warnings using this method.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

BEGIN {
    my $json_installed = eval {
        require JSON;
        1;
    };

    if (! $json_installed) {
        *JSON::true = sub {
            return 'Y';
        };
    }
}

say JSON->true;
```

This is something that should be clearly documented in your module's documentation.

If you actually want to import a function instead of using it with its fully qualified name, the process is similar:

```
BEGIN {
 
    eval {
        require Some::Module;
        import Some::Module qw(addition);
    };
 
    if (! defined &addition){
        *addition = sub {
            my ($x, $y) = @_;
            return $x + $y; 
        };
    }
}

my $added = addition(1, 2);
```

Comment: `1;` isn't needed. `require` returns true or thrown an exception

Answer (score 0):

something like this perhaps (either in its own package like, MaybeJSON.pm or in the top of the script:

```
{
   package JSON;
   sub true { \1 }
   sub false { \0 }
   BEGIN {
      eval { require JSON }
}
```